# How do you avoid dependency hell in Rust projects?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am developing a project that depends on many 3rd party crates.
As it often happens, the 3rd party crates depend on others.

I constantly find myself in a situation where two or more crates require different versions of the same crate. As a result, cargo cannot choose a version.
Often, the problematic crates are those that I do not add explicitly.

Meanwhile, the only solution was to check out a 3rd party and update the version there, but it often requires updating the whole chain of 3rd parties. It takes time and not fun. When I try to publish my changes to the upstream, it takes ages to merge them.

Is there a better way to handle this situation in Rust?

P.S. I come from a C++ background, where dependency management is even worse. So, I do not have much experience with fancy modern eco systems and might miss something.

To give more context, I am adding a partial (the full version is very long) `cargo tree` output.

This is the tree before I add a new dependency:

```
    │   ├── near-chain-configs v0.0.0 (https://github.com/f-squirrel/nearcore.git?rev=76424c004de84f6b5823751f132f62a0da9aa656#0a8e7ac7)
    │   │   ├── anyhow v1.0.75 (*)
    │   │   ├── chrono v0.4.26 (*)
    │   │   ├── derive_more v0.99.17 (proc-macro) (*)
    │   │   ├── near-config-utils v0.0.0 (https://github.com/f-squirrel/nearcore.git?rev=76424c004de84f6b5823751f132f62a0da9aa656#0a8e7ac7)
    │   │   │   ├── anyhow v1.0.75 (*)
    │   │   │   ├── json_comments v0.2.1
    │   │   │   ├── thiserror v1.0.47 (*)
    │   │   │   └── tracing v0.1.37 (*)
    │   │   ├── near-crypto v0.0.0 (https://github.com/f-squirrel/nearcore.git?rev=76424c004de84f6b5823751f132f62a0da9aa656#0a8e7ac7)
    │   │   │   ├── blake2 v0.9.2 (*)
    │   │   │   ├── borsh v0.10.3 (*)
    │   │   │   ├── bs58 v0.4.0
    │   │   │   ├── c2-chacha v0.3.3
    │   │   │   │   ├── cipher v0.2.5
    │   │   │   │   │   └── generic-array v0.14.7 (*)
    │   │   │   │   └── ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
    │   │   │   ├── curve25519-dalek v3.2.0 (*)
    │   │   │   ├── derive_more v0.99.17 (proc-macro) (*)
    │   │   │   ├── ed25519-dalek v1.0.1
    │   │   │   │   ├── curve25519-dalek v3.2.0 (*)
    │   │   │   │   ├── ed25519 v1.5.3
    │   │   │   │   │   └── signature v1.6.4
```

This is the dependency I add:

```ini
[dependencies]
iota-sdk = "1.1.0"
```

The error I receive:

```
error: failed to select a version for `signature`.
    ... required by package `ecdsa v0.16.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ecdsa-core = "^0.16"` of package `k256 v0.13.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `k256 = "^0.13"` of package `iota-crypto v0.21.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iota-crypto = "^0.21.2"` of package `stronghold_engine v2.0.0-rc.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `engine = "^2.0.0-rc.0"` of package `iota_stronghold v2.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iota_stronghold = "^2.0.0"` of package `iota-sdk v1.1.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iota-sdk = "^1.1.0"` of package `iota_client v0.1.0 (/my_lib/iota_client)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `iota_client` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `lib_my_lib v0.1.0 (/my_lib/lib_my_lib)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `lib_my_lib` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `my_lib v0.1.0 (/my_lib/my_lib)`
versions that meet the requirements `^2.0, <2.1` are: 2.0.0

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `signature v2.1.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `signature = "^2"` of package `ed25519 v2.2.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519 = "^2.2.0"` of package `ed25519-zebra v4.0.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519-zebra = "^4.0.1"` of package `iota-crypto v0.23.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iota-crypto = "^0.23.0"` of package `iota-sdk v1.1.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `iota-sdk = "^1.1.0"` of package `iota_client v0.1.0 (/my_lib/iota_client)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `iota_client` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `lib_my_lib v0.1.0 (/my_lib/lib_my_lib)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `lib_my_lib` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `my_lib v0.1.0 (/my_lib/my_lib)`

failed to select a version for `signature` which could resolve this conflict
```

**Update:**

I have tried to run `cargo update` before adding new dependencies to update the version of `signature`  (suggested by [Kevin Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290165/1333734)), but it did not update the version.

Comment: Rust will usually bundle both needed versions of a crate in the case of conflicting versions, unless there's a need for conflicting versions of a C library. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Without a more concrete example of conflicting dependency versions, it is hard to provide a focused answer. Some relevant pages from the Rust Cargo book: [Overriding dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) and [`cargo tree`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html).

Comment: As others have said, your dependencies depending on incompatible versions of some other crate shouldn't be a problem. Cargo can simply include both versions. Here are some exceptions: If some crate depends on a pre-1.0 version of `serde`, you can't serialize and deserialize the structrs in that crate with a current version of serde. You can't have multiple incompatible versions of the Tokio runtime in your crate. And, as pointed out before, you can't link against multiple incompatible versions of the same C library. There may be more exceptions, but without further information, we can't help.

Comment: The only problem I've encountered myself so far is dealing with mutliple incompatible versions of Tokio, which can indeed sometimes be annoying, but this problem comes up less frequently recently, since Tokio 1.0 is now almost three years old, so almost all crates have been updated in the meantime.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah, Tokio is a constant headache. Most of the libs set something like 1.32 instead of 1.0. So once you get a newer version of a crate, something always does not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a typical experience; the blame in this case should be placed on `ecdsa` for **having a `<` version requirement on one of its dependencies.** `<` or `=` requirements cause a package to potentially be not compilable with other packages in the same build, and thus are not good practice in published packages.

`<` and `=` requirements should only be used when:

- there is a bug in later versions of the dependency package that needs to be avoided,
- the dependency is an “internal” library (e.g. a macro library) that no other package should be depending on anyway, or
- you're writing non-public libraries within an organization where you can manage conflicts across the entire dependency graph.

`ecdsa` does not seem to document why it has this requirement, which I consider an omission in their documentation. However, [this commit](https://github.com/RustCrypto/signatures/commit/116528faf25de03e9a637c42bbc28cd8a857908b) indicates that versions of `ecdsa` of `v0.16.5` or later (which is a semver-compatible update) should allow using `signature v2.1.0` and resolve this conflict.

One thing you can try to achieve this state is to run `cargo update` *before* adding new dependencies, in case the problem is prompted by dependency versions already written in your `Cargo.lock` file.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. I ran `cargo update` before adding new dependencies, but `ecdsa` still points to `signature v1.6.4`.

Comment: I have tried to update the problematic crate to use `ecdsa v2` (via Cargo.toml) but it is API-incompatible. Is there any other way, maybe not elegant, to solve the problem?

Comment: @fsquirrel There's no version `2` of `ecdsa`. What's wrong with updating `ecdsa` to `0.16.8`? That is a compatible version and widens the `signature` version range.

Comment: One of the crates "iota-sdk" already depends on it, so it is not a problem.
The other one "near" (cargo tree is in the original post) does not depend on ECDSA but on "ed25519-dalek v1" which requires ed25519 v1.5.3 which depends on signature v1.3.1: https://crates.io/crates/ed25519/1.5.3/dependencies. I do not understand how ecdsa is the problem.

Comment: @fsquirrel "ed25519 v1.5.3 which depends on signature v1.3.1" doesn't affect this problem at all, because major versions are allowed to be duplicated in the dependency graph. That is, Cargo will pick a `signature v1.*` separately from picking a `signature v2.*`. Your conflict is in the `2.*` space.

Comment: It seems it got fixed! Thank you very very much for the explanation and your patience, Kevin!